# Scrollbar movement SetScrollPos and SendMessage

Tags: c#, winapi, scrollbar, sendmessage

I'm trying to move the scrollbar of a window programatically. I'm first sending a :

```
SetScrollPos(handle, 1, position, true);
```

and then followed by :

```
SendMessage(handle, 0x0115, wparam, new IntPtr(0));
```

The wparam is correct. When i inspect through spy++, the only difference between sending a scroll with the above code and actually scrolling is that in the actual scroll, the message nesting level is 1 but here it is zero. But that apart, all the other properties and same, the WM_VSCROLL, handle, position, wparam etc. But the programatic scroll doesn't move the bar.
Any suggestions on what im doing wrong???

P.S: Trying to do this from a c# application
THanks a ton!

EDIT: when i pass SB_BOTTOM to the wparam, it takes me correctly to the end of the scroll.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to use [SetScrollInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787595%28VS.85%29.aspx) function instead of manually sending messages.

Comment: I've tried SetScrollInfo and it doesn't seem to be working for me. The SendMessage works in all cases except where i try to send an exact position with SB_THUMBPOSITION as the loword and the position as the hiword in the wparam.

Comment: I believe that you have wrong p/invoke for SetScrollInfo, or maybe using it incorrectly, because this function is WinApi and 100% working. Try to play with it, or show your p/invoke interfaces for SetScrollInfo and usage examples.